# How to color cell in overleaf?

Tags: tables, color, overleaf

I'm using [this table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/#) and I generated this table:

[image]

Generator gave me code:

```
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
% If you use beamer only pass "xcolor=table" option, i.e. \documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Features       & Algorithm 1                   & Algorithm 2                   \\ \hline
First feature  & 0.384                         & \cellcolor[HTML]{96FFFB}0.853 \\
Second feature & \cellcolor[HTML]{96FFFB}0.289 & 0.12                          \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

which I entered to my overleaf code. However the output is the following:

[image]

Do you know why I don't have my cells colored? I was looking there is the problem but I have no idea why. Do you know how code should look like to achieve this result?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you loaded package `xcolor`?

Comment: Yes I did, I used command `\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}` at the beginning of document. Is there anything more that I have to do?

Comment: Which document class do you use?

Comment: please provide a small but complete document that fails to colour the table, we can not debug the fragment provided the output you show would indicate that `xcolor` package is not loaded.

Comment: Do you get any errors in Overleaf (red icon top left above the pdf output)?

Comment: I use `\documentclass{article}`

Comment: I do not get any error or warning

Comment: Apart from a float warning `LaTeX Warning: No positions in optional float specifier.`, your code runs well on overleaf's texlive2021, with `\documentclass{article} \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}`.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}%<<< added
 

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Features       & Algorithm 1                   & Algorithm 2                   \\ \hline
First feature  & 0.384                         & \cellcolor[HTML]{96FFFB}0.853 \\
Second feature & \cellcolor[HTML]{96FFFB}0.289 & 0.12                          \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: According to a comment from the asker (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/625246/how-to-color-cell-in-overleaf/635619#comment1560771_625246) they already tried this and it did not work. Possibly they already had a previous `\usepackage{xcolor}` statement somewhere, even though they claim there are no errors when compiling. In any case, your answer does not seem to solve the actual problem in this question (and neither does the answer of Johnsonn), even though your code is correct in itself.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution with using `tabularray` and `siunitx` package. (loaded as `tabularray` library):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}%<<< added
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx, varwidth}
\NewTableCommand\SCC[1]{\SetCell{bg=#1}}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec={c *{2}{Q[c, si={table-format=1.3}]} },
             measure=vbox}
\SCC{yellow!30}  Features       
                & {{{Algorithm 1}}}   
                        & {{{Algorithm 2}}}     \\
First feature   & 0.384 & \SCC{cyan!30}  0.853  \\
Second feature  & \SCC{cyan!30}  0.289 
                        & 0.12                  \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put this instruction \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} at the very beginning of the document juste after \documentclass.
It just worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).