# I want to make table in latex which looks little complicated to write the command. Help to make a complicated table

Tags: tables

[image]
An example of the table is shown below. Exact table I want to make is on latex.

Comment: On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: As starting point may serve  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/625246/how-to-color-cell-in-overleaf/635628#635628.

Answer (score 1):

try with [tablesgenerator.com](https://tablesgenerator.com/), works to me!

here's a silly example, which might not be the best latex code produced:

[image: silly example]

embed its code snippet in your document:

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &                       &                       \\ \hline
                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{3-5} 
                       &                       &                       &                       &                       \\
                       &                       &                       &                       &                      
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Please elaborate a bit more next time, see my edits: answers shall be code-solutions in this place.