# Custom table (maybe) using multicolumn

Tags: tables, multicolumn

Im currently struggling with a table i latex.
I want a table like this:

[image]

I have found a way to make a normal table like {|c|c|} and then make the title with multicolumn.

The real struggle I have is in row 2 and 4. When using multicolumn I cannot figure out how to split the text inside the box.

And how do I move the vertical line splitting the boxes from row 2 to 4?

Hope you can help!

Comment: Start with a table which has 4 columns.

Comment: Any news? Does answer with comment fulfil your expectation?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As is suggested in @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{width=88mm,
             hlines, vlines,
             colspec = { *{4}{X[l]} },
               hspan = minimal
             }
\SetCell[c=4]{c}    some text
        &       &       &               \\
\SetCell[c=2]{} some longer text in two lines
        &       &   \SetCell[c=2]{} some longer text in two lines
                        &               \\
\SetCell[c=4]{c}    some text     
        &       &       &               \\
\SetCell[c=3]{} some longer text in one line
        &       &       &   some text   \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! But now with the tabularray, how do I color some of the cells?

Comment: @Emilie, simple. In preamble load `xcolor` package and than selected cells color by `\SetCell{fg=red, bg=yellow}  <cell text>`. See  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/625246/, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/629708/ and of course, package documentation where is coloring thoroughly described with lot of examples. BTW, in question you not mentioned this problem...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to create that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}[width=88mm,hvlines]{X[2]X[1]X[1]}
\Block{1-3}{some text} \\
\Block[l,v-center]{1-1}{some longer text in two lines}
& \Block[l,v-center]{1-2}{some longer text in two\\ lines in the tabular}& \\
\Block{1-3}{some text} \\
\Block[l]{1-2}{some longer text in one line} & & some text 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]